# Convert Modern Team site into Modern Communication Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site, modern-team-site

Is it possible to convert a Modern Team Site into Modern Communication Site?

User created a site with Team Site template, but not it appears the requirement are more in alignment with Communication Site Template. Is it possible to convert it to Communication site without having to re-create the entire site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid not.

It is not supported to change site template in SharePoint. You can only find a way to enable communication site experience on modern team sites.
There is an OOB method for [classic team site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modernize-classic-team-site) but not modern team sites though.

I would suggest you use [Site designs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview) to apply custom experience, or just rebuild a communication site instead.

Comment: Ok, then will have to recreate it only i believe.